# How to normalize LCS algorithm result in a way that strings's length won't affect?

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming, stl-algorithm, lcs

I have `n` strings (each has its own size) and the letters are included in finite group - `S` (~ 120 letters).
I want to calculate LCS result between each string to another and I want that all results will be normalized.

I want to normalize LCS result between `string i` and `string j` to avoid both strings's length.

Example:
`LCS("shpin","shdek")=2` because `("[sh]pin","[sh]dek") = "sh"`
**but**
`LCS("shpxaaaaaaaaaan","shaaaaaaaaaadek")=12` because `("[sh]px[aaaaaaaaaa]n","[shaaaaaaaaaa]dek") = "shaaaaaaaaaa"`

I was thinking about dividing each result in `Expected Value` but I don't know to calculate `EV`.
Does anyone have a solution? maybe another way to get good enough approximation? :(

Thanks

Comment: Could you maybe include sample input and expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by "normalization?"

Comment: I got a mistake, I don't know how to calculate Expected Value between two random sequences. does anyone know? maybe another way to get a good approximate result? :(